# Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "WinMergeU.exe"

Tags: ant

I am given my ant script code here .thanks for advance

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="sample1" default="ex1" >
<import file="./property.xml"/>
<target name="ex1"  description="winmergeex" >
<exec dir="${winmergedir}" executable="WinMergeU.exe">
<arg value="D:\winme\buid.xml" />
<arg value="D:\winme\buid.xml" />
<arg value="D:\winme\build1.xml" />
</exec>
</target>
</project>
```

Property.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="propertyexample">
<property name="winmergedir" value="D:\software\WinMerge-2.14.0-exe" />
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="sample1" default="help4" >
<import file="./property.xml"/>         
<target name="help4">  
<exec executable="${winmer}" spawn="true">            
<arg value="${arg1}"/>
<arg value="${arg2}"/>
</exec>
</target>   
</project>   


property.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="propertyexample">     
<property name="arg1" value="D:\winme\ori\" />
<property name="arg2" value="D:\winme\dup\" />    
<property name="winmer" location="C:/Program Files/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe"/>
</project>
```

I need mentioned WinMergeU.exe path location and i need to pass two aruments leftside path and right side path.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the right way to do it but I was facing similar issue so what I did is I gave absolute path of the executable to it and it worked fine.